# Change the Django Rest Framework Default Router api root?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, root

In development,

my defaultrouter works along the base url/domain of http://127.0.0.1:8000/, however the api is going to be hosted on http://website.com/test/location/

How do i change the default default router location so apiview,inner links, and the api work at  http://website.com/test/location/ as the api root?

Answer (score 0):

Your default router has nothing to deal with the domain. It only generates patterns to be matched after the domain name.

Let's say you have the following default router:

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', views.UserViewSet)
```

That means `/users/` will be matched to some view no matter what the domain is. So for the developement process it will match `127.0.0.1:800/users/` and `localhost:8000/users/`. After you deploy it to `website.com/`, it will match `website.com/users/`

In most cases the domain is changed automatically as you deploy it to some platform or server.